# Dynamic Compilation in Haskell GHC API Error

Tags: api, haskell, compiler-construction, ghc, dynamic-compilation

I have been trying to get some basic dynamic code compilation working using the GHC API by following a tutorial found [here](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2008/11/dynamic-compilation-and-loading-of.html).

This code:

```
import GHC
import GHC.Paths
import DynFlags
import Unsafe.Coerce

main :: IO ()
main =
    defaultErrorHandler defaultDynFlags $ do
      func <- runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
        dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
        setSessionDynFlags dflags
        target <- guessTarget "Test.hs" Nothing
        addTarget target
        r <- load LoadAllTargets
        case r of
          Failed -> error "Compilation failed"
          Succeeded -> do
            m <- findModule (mkModuleName "Test") Nothing
            setContext [] [m]
            value <- compileExpr ("Test.print")
            do let value' = (unsafeCoerce value) :: String -> IO ()
               return value'
      func "Hello"
      return ()
```

Should get the print function from another file called Test.hs, load it and run its print function.

I compile the code with ghc version 7.4.1 using the command:

```
ghc -package ghc --make Api.hs
```

But receive the following error:

```
Api.hs:8:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `Severity' with actual type `Settings'
    Expected type: LogAction
      Actual type: Settings -> DynFlags
    In the first argument of `defaultErrorHandler', namely
      `defaultDynFlags'
    In the expression: defaultErrorHandler defaultDynFlags
```

What am I doing wrong? I have checked the GHC API docs but am not well versed enough in this kind of thing to understand most of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial is out of date. In ghc-7.0.* and previous, the type of `defaultErorHandler` was

```
defaultErrorHandler :: (ExceptionMonad m, MonadIO m) => DynFlags -> m a -> m a
```

and `defaultDynFlags` was just a value.

As of ghc-7.2.*, the type of `defaultErrorHandler` is

```
defaultErrorHandler :: (ExceptionMonad m, MonadIO m) => LogAction -> m a -> m a
```

`defaultDynFlags` is a function

```
defaultDynFlags :: Settings -> DynFlags
```

and `LogAction` is a synonym

```
type LogAction = Severity -> SrcSpan -> PprStyle -> Message -> IO ()
```

In 7.6, it has changed again, we now have

```
defaultErrorHandler :: (ExceptionMonad m, MonadIO m) => FatalMessager -> FlushOut -> m a -> m a
```

with

```
type FatalMessager = String -> IO ()
```

and `FlushOut` being a `newtype` wrapper around `IO ()`.

I'm not very familiar with the GHC Api (a too fast-moving target for me), so I'm not sure how the working code should look like, but for the 7.2 and 7.4 series, the first argument to `defaultErrorHandler` should probably be `defaultLogAction`.

Also the type of `setContext` has changed, I don't know if what I have does what you want, but it compiles (with 7.4.2; but you also need the `ghc-paths` package in addition to `ghc` for the `GHC.Paths` module) - I haven't tried to run it, though.

```
import GHC
import GHC.Paths
import DynFlags
import Unsafe.Coerce

main :: IO ()
main =
    defaultErrorHandler defaultLogAction $ do
      func <- runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
        dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
        setSessionDynFlags dflags
        target <- guessTarget "Test.hs" Nothing
        addTarget target
        r <- load LoadAllTargets
        case r of
          Failed -> error "Compilation failed"
          Succeeded -> do
            m <- findModule (mkModuleName "Test") Nothing
            setContext [IIModule m]
            value <- compileExpr ("Test.print")
            do let value' = (unsafeCoerce value) :: String -> IO ()
               return value'
      func "Hello"
      return ()
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to compile fine. However, when I run it, it works fine the first time- It compiles the Test.hs file and runs the print function to print out the word "Hello". However, If I try to run it a second time, I get the error message "mkTopLevEnv: not interpreted main:Test"

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work with compiled modules. If you delete the `.hi` and `.o` files between runs, it would probably work multiple times. But that's somewhat inconvenient, isn't it? So you'd need a way that can handle compiled modules. Unfortunately, I don't know the API well enough to be able to tell you how to do that. Could be your next question here.

Comment: I just solved this after much trying: Two things helped me: (1) ´do {dflags <- getSessionDynFlags;setSessionDynFlags $ dflags {hscTarget = HscInterpreted,ghcLink   = LinkInMemory}´ to make it reload the context each run and (2) Use IIDecl instead of IIModule to make it less error prone and safe. Also, `parseImportDecl` is nice to get the IIDecl. Ask me for more info if needed, right now I need sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example for dynamic loading, also hosted [here](https://gist.github.com/worldsayshi/8853946):

### DynLoad.hs

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | Example for loading Haskell source code dynamically using the GHC api
-- Useful links:
-- GHC api:
-- http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html
-- Wiki:
-- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/As_a_library
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
module DynLoad where

import GHC
import GhcMonad (liftIO)
import GHC.Paths (libdir)
import Name (getOccString)
import Data.Dynamic (fromDyn)

-- |  List all exports of this module
--    and evaluate a symbol from a module DynTest 
main = 
  runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
    putString ":::Display exports of modules:::"
    modSums <- initSession ["DynLoad","DynTest"]
    let thisModSum = head modSums
    exports <- listExports thisModSum
    mapM_ putString exports

    putString ":::Evaluate a name from module DynTest:::"
    importDecl_RdrName <- parseImportDecl "import DynTest as D"
    setContext [IIDecl importDecl_RdrName]
    dynVal <- dynCompileExpr "D.aString"
    liftIO $ print $ (fromDyn dynVal "nope-nothing")

-- | Init interactive session and load modules
initSession modStrNames = do
  dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
  setSessionDynFlags $ dflags {
    hscTarget = HscInterpreted
    , ghcLink   = LinkInMemory
    }
  targets <- mapM
              (\modStrName -> do
                  putString modStrName
                  target <- guessTarget ("*"++modStrName++".hs") Nothing
                  return target
              ) modStrNames
  setTargets targets
  load LoadAllTargets
  modSums <- mapM
              (\modStrName -> do
                  putString modStrName
                  modSum <- getModSummary $ mkModuleName modStrName
                  return $ ms_mod modSum
              ) modStrNames
  return modSums

-- | List exported names of this or a sibling module
listExports mod = do
  maybeModInfo <- getModuleInfo mod
  case maybeModInfo of
    (Just modInfo) -> do
      let expNames = modInfoExports modInfo
          expStrNames = map getOccString expNames
      return expStrNames
    _ -> return []

-- | Util for printing
putString = liftIO . putStrLn
```

And here is an example file to load:

### DynTest.hs

```
module DynTest where


aString = "Hello"
```